How to find the native library for a specific native method in android Java code?
I am having a function in an apk that looks like this:

I want to find the .so file that contains executable code for this function.
What I tried:

I tried looking for calls to System.loadlibrary() in the same class but found none.
I enumerated loaded libraries using frida but none of them contain any hint about this method (or I have not known what to look for).
I found classes that extended this k class, but found none.

Please help!

Native method implementations can be contained in any loaded .so file. They just have to be present (loaded) when the native method is called. I would first check the .so files for exported methods that match the JNI method naming scheme (start with Java_ and the package and class name). Note that AFAIK it is also possible to define native methods in an .so e.g. in JNI_OnLoad, therefore native method implementations are not always exported functions.
